# MySQL Create User and Grant Permission Script

Tags: php, mysql

So i am trying to put together a simple membership site on my localhost using mysql and php as well as html and css. I am using a class to try to keep my php OOP called DbConnection which has methods to Select, insert, update, and delete, as well as connect and disconnect from the database. I have no problem making a connection and inserting the users to my specific table. My problem lies with granting the newly created user permissions to create, delete , insert, or update any data. Is there a bug in my grantUserStandardPermissions() function ? Or am i not allowed to run multiple queries?

My Database : db_test
Tables: Users, products, orders, wishlist

I want to store these users in my Users table in my db_test. NOT ON MY mysql.user table!

Please Help!

Here is what I have:

I connect to the database with this function:

```
   /*=================================================================*/
//
// Function creates the connecton to the database   
public function connect(){

    // If there is no connection already in existence
    if(!$this->con){

    // Create the Connection to the database, the object oriented way
     $this->connection = @mysql_connect($this->IP_ADDRESS, $this->DB_USER, $this->DB_PASSWORD, $this->DB_NAME) or die(@mysqli_err());

        // If the connection was successful
        if($this->connection){

            // Connect to the Body Block Database
            $select_database = @mysql_select_db($this->DB_NAME, $this->connection);

            // If the Body Block database was selected
            if($select_database){

                // Connection was successful alert the user
                echo 'Connected to the Database<br/>';

                // Set the Connection to true
                $this->con = true;

                // Return tre
                return true;

            // Else the database was not selected    
            }else{

                // Could not find the database
                echo 'The Database does not Exist<br/>';

                // Return false
                return false;              
            }

        // Else, the connection was unsuccessful    
        }else{

            // Unable to connect, server problem
            echo 'Unable to make a connection.<br/>';

            // Return false
            return false;          
        }
    // There is a connection already    
    }else{

        // Already connected
        echo 'A connection to the database already exists.<br/>';

        // Return true
        return true;         
    }
} // End connect()
```

Then i insert a user with this function:

```
/*=================================================================*/
//
// Function creates a new row with the passed in data
public function insert($table_name, $values, $rows = null){

    // If the table exists
    if($this->tableExists($table_name)){

        // The query statement to run is created
        $this->query = 'INSERT INTO ' .$table_name;

        // If rows where passed in
        if($rows != null){

            // implode the rows array at a comma
            $rows = implode(',', $rows);

            // Append the rows to the query
            $this->query .= ' ('.$rows.')';

        }

            // Loop throught the values we want to insert
            for($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++){

                // If the values are strings
                if(is_string($values[$i])){

                    // Set the values as strings to insert
                    $values[$i] = '\''.$values[$i].'\'';
                }
            }

            // Implode the values where there is a ,
            $values = implode(',',$values);

            // Create the insert query to run on the database
            $this->query .= 'VALUES ('. $values.')';

            echo "$this->query"."<br/>";

            // Run the query against the database
            $result = mysql_query($this->query);

            // If there is a result
            if($result){

                // Echo the Success
                echo 'Success';

                // Return true
                return true;

            // Else there is no result    
            }else{

                // Return false
                return false;
            }
     // Else the table does not exist   
    }else{

        echo 'Failed to find table!';

        // Return false
        return false;
    }
}// End insert()
```

Then i Try to give this user permissions using this function:

**UPDATE** - I dropped this function, and created the users using my all access administrator, then created a second administrator to handle CRUD, thus querying my user table for the user, trying to perform the operations.

```
 //=============================================================================
// Grant the permissions for the new User
public function grantUserStandardPermissions($username, $password){
    $grantPermission = "GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON db_test.* TO ";
    $grantPermission .= $username;
    $grantPermission .= " @'%' IDENTIFIED BY '". $password. "'";

    echo "$grantPermission";

    $result = mysql_query($grantPermission);

    if($result){
        mysql_query("FLUSH PRIVELAGES");
        echo 'ran command';
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I would like to point out that it's very strange to have to write PHP code that adds a MySQL user. Typically you have one user for your application, which has full access to the application tables (and maybe read access on some mysql tables). Unless you're writing a database management tool of course.

Comment: Yes, this is how i am doing it. The users table is inside my db_test database. Sorry i need to make this more clear. I have a standard administrative user, that handles all the connections etc. but the problem is my users can't get an permission to CRUD on the database.

Comment: That is not how you should be doing it. MySQL users should be applications. Your application will likely have a `users` table that lists all the users of your application. All those users will use the _same_ mysql connection/credentials. You should only have to set up the CRUD rights once for your application. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Okay, so your saying if i keep using my admin account to update, delete, create, insert data I will only need to check first if the person trying to use my admin account is in the Users table?

Comment: Yes and no. You shouldn't use an admin account for an application, the admin account is for you, make a new user with limited rights for the application. The application doesn't need permissions to add new mysql users and add new tables etc. For development this might be fine but not for live. Your application will have one mysql user, and it's own users table.

Comment: Awesome Frits, this was exactly the answer i was looking for. Can you provide it as an answer and i will accept it. Basically what i am going to do now is create a default admin, that is in charge of all database setup. Then i will create a standard permission user lets call him admin-test and i will use this admin-test to insert new users into the users table. And i will use the Users table to make sure the person creating data is in my Users table. This sound right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I initialize MySQL db I run:

```
SET sql_safe_updates=0;

delete from mysql.user where user = '';
commit;

CREATE SCHEMA `petshop` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;

CREATE USER `petshop-dml` identified by 'petshop-dml123';

GRANT SELECT ON petshop.* TO `petshop-dml`;
GRANT INSERT ON petshop.* TO `petshop-dml`;
GRANT UPDATE ON petshop.* TO `petshop-dml`;
GRANT DELETE ON petshop.* TO `petshop-dml`;
GRANT EXECUTE ON petshop.* TO `petshop-dml`;

//optionally create your own user, that executes DDLs:
//CREATE USER `petshop-admin` identified by 'petshop-admin123';
//GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `petshop-admin`@'%';
```

Adjust schema, password and username to your needs and execute it for example from PHP Admin or whatever tool you like :)

Then use created user (in this example `petshop-dml`) in you application to insert, update, delete, query.

Comment: So i can drop my Grant Logic completely. And use the above code to create my user and grant those permissions via command line or Stored procedure?

Comment: This was the solution I went with. I created two separate users, one to do the SUPER admin DROP, CREATE, GRANT etc. And one for the CRUD operations.